# Which robotic simulation tool fits my need

Tags: visualization, simulation, robotics, avatar

Im trying to analyze which software products out there, that could fit into a product idea.

- I want a robotic simulation tool, that can show a model of a
  selfdrawn robot.
- It shall be possible to control the selfdrawn robot    through a
  programming interface. C,java,c++.. or maybe multiple or a selfdescribed
  programming interface.
- In order to make this product easy to use, the programming interface
  should be simple for the user and the execution of the code on the
  drawn model aswell.
- It has to run on windows.

Eather im looking for a tool that can do all these things, or im looking for a tool that is easy to change/extend for the wanted look and feel.

Plaese help if you have some good tips within this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do.

"ROS" is a good simulation environment and it can provide your robot with simulated sensor data from the simulation.  So for example you place a wall in the simulation and your robot can get maybe laser scanner or ultrasound distance from the wall.   Of cousre you'd have to write the model for the sensor but ROS can provide updates to the wall to sensor distance an as the robot drives around.

ROS is neat because it can run on multiple computers and passes data between nodes.  Some no=des can be simulations some can be inside real robot hardware.

If your "robot" is less sophisticated and really is just a remote control object your user directly controls then look at a game environment.  "jmonkey" is one and can animate game characters in a "world" you build.   If your robot can be represented by a video game character money would work.  It runs and every platform from Windows to Android.

Both are big software systems with learning curves.

BTW anything will run on Windows in the have VMware installed ;-)